# How to delete .svn folder from a SVN repository

Tags: macos, svn

Issue:

While loading a dump to a repository, getting below mentioned exception.

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
svnadmin: E160020: File already exists: filesystem '/ngs/app/istsvnp/SVNROOT/ACENTERPRISE/db', transaction '805-mv', path 'branches'
```

Using following command to load to the repository

```
svnadmin load --bypass-prop-validation ~/SVNROOT/ACENTERPRISE < $NGS1/acenterprise.dump
```

But when I load the dump (`acenterprise.dump`) to another test repository, I could able to load properly.

Issue looks like, when I checked out the repository ACENTERPRISE in my desktop, could see that there is a `.svn` folder present.

Is `.svn` folder is causing the issue (not loading the dump)
How can I delete the `.svn` folder from the working copy of the repository and commit the changes to server.

Please help.

Comment: Are you attempting to load into an existing repository which already has revisions in it?

Comment: Initially when I loaded the dump into the ACENTERPRISE repository which was a blank one, after revision 800, got the exception as -     <<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 401 
svnadmin: E160020: File already exists: filesystem '/ngs/app/istsvnp/SVNROOT/ACENTERPRISE/db', transaction '800-me', path 'trunk'            Then I checked out the code and deleted all checked in codes, but can see still a.svn folder exists in working copy. Later on whenever I trying to load - getting exception as- svnadmin: E160020: File already exists

Comment: "Then I checked out the code and deleted all checked in codes, but can see still a.svn folder exists in working copy" - The `.svn` directory is completely correct, see my answer below. As for the rest, I think you're making things worse by trying more or less random things hoping it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

The `.svn` directory is purely a client-side construct. It's created and used by the client to connect a working copy (what you checked out) back to the server. It does not exist on the server and should never find its way into the repository.

If you are attempting to load a dumpfile into a pre-existing repository that already has activity in it, that will require some additional effort and it will make working with older revisions...weird. If that's what you really need to do, see the following links:

- [Merging a part of SVN repository to another repository with history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579536/merging-a-part-of-svn-repository-to-another-repository-with-history)
- http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/32115-combine-two-repositories